# http request always blocked in container of k8s cluster pod

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Stages:

1. connect a container's shell
2. curl www.xxx.com (//this will always waiting )
   ...

Then I use `tcpdump` in host machine and filter by ip
`tcpdump -i eth0 host ip`

```
3   11:05:05 2019/12/2  133.5701630 10.171.162.231  111.111.222.333 TCP TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=......S., SrcPort=48836, DstPort=HTTP(80), PayloadLen=0, Seq=126843476, Ack=0, Win=29200 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x7 ) = 29200
4   11:05:05 2019/12/2  133.5704230 111.111.222.333 10.171.162.231  TCP TCP:Flags=...A..S., SrcPort=HTTP(80), DstPort=48836, PayloadLen=0, Seq=3228156738, Ack=126843477, Win=2896 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x9 ) = 1482752
5   11:05:05 2019/12/2  133.5704630 10.171.162.231  111.111.222.333 TCP TCP: [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=48836, DstPort=HTTP(80), PayloadLen=0, Seq=126843477, Ack=3228156739, Win=229 (scale factor 0x7) = 29312
6   11:05:05 2019/12/2  133.5705430 10.171.162.231  111.111.222.333 HTTP    HTTP:Request, GET /api/test, Query:debug
7   11:05:05 2019/12/2  133.5707110 111.111.222.333 10.171.162.231  TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTP(80), DstPort=48836, PayloadLen=0, Seq=3228156739, Ack=126843596, Win=6 (scale factor 0x9) = 3072
```

The tcp flag is

```
src -> dst syn
dst -> src syn/ack
src -> dst ack
src -> dst ack/push
dst -> src ack
```

The `curl` command will waiting a long time and then throw a timeout error. in normal request there has a `dst -> src ack/push` packet, but I never received.

I don't know why and how to resolve it.

--- my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app-dep
  labels:
    app: test-app
    version: stable
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
      version: stable
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
        version: stable
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: test-app
        name: test-app

        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health/status
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: It can be because of multiple reasons. It's difficult to guess the problem with your curl command with the given information. Please add the YAML files, to give a better understanding of your configurations and maybe then someone would be able to help you.

Comment: @RewanthCool i update my question.  i have two cluster , only one cluster have this problem, so i dont think this is config reason.

Comment: This is happening with all pods or on this specific deployment?

Comment: yes. all pod will happened in this cluster

Comment: @quanweili What is the health status of the deployment? Is the service up and running on port 80? If possible can you share the image name you are using in the above deployment file so that we can try to replicate it on our end too?